# How to write a UTF-8 file?

Tags: export

```
s = OpenWrite[ofile, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
Export[s, "∂f/∂t"]
Close[s]
```

did not successfully write `∂` into the file.  Instead, it writes the `InputForm`. How to let it write `∂`?

Comment: AFAIK Export and OpenWrite have no relationship whatsoever. I find it a small wonder that you can even use a file handle in Export.

Comment: Really?  No wonder.  My guess is Export[file, ...] internally will create file handle any way and using file handle directly probably just mean a replacement didn't occur.  It might be an accident due to implementation details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F'x is correct. Using `WriteString` is the method to use. If you want to write a "big expression", try the following.

Let's assume a large matrix with dimensions of 100 by 5;

```
a = RandomReal[{1,10},{100,5}]
```

We can easily write this using the `WriteString` method.

```
s = OpenWrite["~/Desktop/toto.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
WriteString[s, a]
Close[s]
```

This will write to the text file exactly as you see it printed in the notebook interface.

[image]

You can also print in `Grid` or `TableForm`

```
a = RandomReal[{1,10},{100,5}]//TableForm
```

[image]

You can also get a little crazy and riffle in delimiters...

```
a = "a =   "<> StringJoin[Riffle[ToString[#^2] & /@ Range[10], "\t"]]
```

[image]

Also, don't forget the `OpenAppend` function to write data at the end of a file without overwriting existing info.

```
b = "b =   " <> StringJoin[Riffle[ToString[#^3] & /@ Range[10], "\t"]]
s = OpenAppend["~/Desktop/toto.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
WriteString[s, "\n"]
WriteString[s, b]
Close[s]
```

Answer (score 4):

**`WriteString`**:

```
s = OpenWrite["~/Desktop/toto.txt", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
WriteString[s, "\[PartialD]f/\[PartialD]t"]
Close[s]
```

Comment: But I have a big expression to write.  Not just a string.